# laravel TokenMismatchException in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using resource group and use this filter to resolve `TokenMismatchException` problem:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function($route, $request) {
    if (strtoupper($request -> getMethod()) === 'GET') {
        return;
        // get requests are not CSRF protected
    }

    $token = $request -> ajax() ? $request -> header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');

    if (Session::token() != $token) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

my route :

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin', 'before' => 'csrf'), function(){
    Route::resource('profile' , 'ProfileController', array('as'=>'profile') );
});
```

now. i get error to Ajax requests such as this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#frm').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           name         = $('#name').val();
           family       = $('#family').val();
           email        = $('#email').val();
           currPassword = $('#currPassword').val();
           password     = $('#password').val();
           password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();     

           $.post("{{ route('admin.profile.update', $profile->id) }}",
                { 
                  _method : 'PUT',
                  name                  : name,
                  family                : family,
                  email                 : email,
                  currPassword          : currPassword,
                  password              : password,
                  password_confirmation : password_confirmation  
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    alert(data.errors.name);
                },'json');
                return false;
       });
});
</script>
```

ERROR:

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Session\\TokenMismatchException","message":"","file":"\/var\/www\/alachiq\/app\/filters.php","line":83}}
```

i think i'm must be sent _token in `$.post`. but i can not get `input` tag with `name` attribute. iget this error:

```
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
```

Answer (score 51):

There is a tip in the Laravel docs on how to do this.  This might not have been available at the time of the question, but I thought I would update it with a answer.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

I have tested the meta tag method from the documentation and got it working.  Add the following meta tag into your global template

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Add this JavaScript that sets defaults for all ajax request in jQuery.  Preferably in a js file that is included across your app.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})
```

This token can exist in the request header or the form.  This populates it into the request header of every ajax request.

Comment: Hi Paul! Is this safe even if I have a lot of forms in my website? I'm just thinking about it, because I'm using templates and I'm extending it to all my views.

Comment: Yes, the amount of forms has no bearing on this.  It is just adding a http header into each ajax request.

Answer (score 13):

You have to insert a hidden input with the _token and later get that value as you do to get the other form fields in your ajax post.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**An another method,**

On your view you can set an object with the _token

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _globalObj = {{ json_encode(array('_token'=> csrf_token())) }}
</script>
```

and later on your ajax call you can get the _token from the object like this:

```
var token = _globalObj._token;
```

and include it on your ajax post.

Comment: i'm using `{{ Form::model() }}`and this can inserted `_token` hidden `input` tag. this is not my problem

Comment: while you do your ajax post, do you see the _token field passed? if so is that correct/same with the one in your session?

Comment: yes this is correct and after i have `Route::resource('profile' , 'ProfileController', array('as'=>'profile') );` into `group`, i have this problem.

Answer (score 10):

***Just do simple thing as i have shown in following code,***

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your-post-route-url',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "form_data": $('#Form').serialize(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (reject) {
            console.log(reject);
        }
    });
```

I hope this one is the easiest way to solve this problem without any hidden field and it works for me in laravel 5.4 version :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's only good for inline javascript and can't be used in external javascript files

Answer (score 3):

You can as well add the url thats giving you the error inside the `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file in the

```
protected $except = [
    //
]
```

Let's say your route is post. You can just add in like this

```
protected $except = ['post',
    //
];`...
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: simplest solution

Comment: This isn't secure. Someone could abuse this open endpoint without the CsrfToken protection.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Ajax Example</title>
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>" />    
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });
  </script>

  <script>
     function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
           data:'',
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
        });
     }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>


  <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
     Click the button to replace the message.</div>
  <?php
     echo Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
  ?>
  </br>


  </body>

  </html>
```

and `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file add this function

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    // If request is an ajax request, then check to see if token matches token provider in
    // the header. This way, we can use CSRF protection in ajax requests also.
    $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```