# token mismatching ajax in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, token

```
 $('#id').change(function(){
        var a = $('#id_one').val();
        var token = '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>';
        $.ajax({
         url: "url",
         type: 'POST',
         data: {'id':a,'_token':token},
         success: function(data)
            {
             // some code
            }
        });
    })
```

This is my code.
Getting token mismatch error..!!
I have tried both of the following..

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var _globalObj = {{ json_encode(array('_token'=> csrf_token())) }}
```

Can any one help ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel TokenMismatchException in ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627170/laravel-tokenmismatchexception-in-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize your token from the blade template, just declare your session token in the blade file of your view under the script tag like this:

```
<script> var token = '{{ Session::token() }}'; </script>
```

and call the token in ajax, in your code it will be something like this:

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    var a = $('#id_one').val();
    $.ajax({
     url: "url",
     type: 'POST',
     data: {'id':a,'_token':token},
     success: function(data)
        {
         // some code
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because the token field name should be `_token` and not `token`

Also If this javascript code in a separate javascript file then php function will not work.

Also if the data you are trying to send is of a form then you can do this

```
 $('#id').change(function(){
        var data = $("#form").serialize() ;
        $.ajax({
         url: "url",
         type: 'POST',
         data: data,
         success: function(data)
            {
             // some code
            }
        });
    })
```

where your form looks like

```
<form id="form">
<input type='hidden' value='{{ csrf_token() }}' name='_token'>
<input type="text" name='id'>
</form>
```

Comment: that is variable only in which i'm just storing.
Is that make any sense ?

and i also tried by passing it in hidden field,still not working...

Comment: Change your `token` variable to `_token` and tell me if its working. Also make sure that the laravel middlewares are untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            url: someurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data     : formData,
            headers: {
                    "x-csrf-token": $("#token").data('id')
                }
            });
    }
```

and in your html

```
       <div id="token" data-id="{!! csrf_token() !!}"></div>
```