# TokenMismatchException laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to understand why a post request make TokenMismatchException. 
I tried yet the standard solution to add

`<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

and

```
headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')}
```

but when I click to submit button, chrome console log show me

> jquery.js:8625 POST http://local.game/play 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.js:8625ajax @ jquery.js:8161(anonymous function) @ index.js:10dispatch @ jquery.js:4430r.handle @ jquery.js:4116

Thanks in advance

This is the error

```
    Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

This is my js now

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.login-input').on('focus', function () {
        $('.login').addClass('focused');
    });

    $('.login').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('.login-input').val();
        var token = $('#token').val();
        $('.login').removeClass('focused').addClass('loading');
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')},
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/play',
            data: JSON.stringify({'data': data, "_token": token}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'array'
        });
    });
});

xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

this is the line with the error

Comment: Where you see `TokenMismatchException` error ?

Comment: So, I have a landing page that user uses to insert his name and a play button. After click play button I pass the control to js that make ajax call with url: "/play". In laravel web.php file I add the route Route::post('/play', 'provaController@index');

Comment: I mean there's no `TokenMismatchException` error in the error posted.

Comment: Post your js code also.

Comment: check here, if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627170/laravel-tokenmismatchexception-in-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the ajax request that you have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/<url>',
    data: JSON.stringify({id: '<?php echo $job->id?>', "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

So you data will be like

```
id: something,
_token: <the actual token>
```

You don't need to do JSON

Here is a link to the [CSRF documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf) part

Comment: The OP already passing `headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')}` in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You've a double token in your page try to remove one of them, so use `meta` tag and remove `#token` from the document like :

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')},
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/play',
    data: JSON.stringify({'data': data}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'array'
});
```

Or just `#token` in remove meta from the document :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/play',
    data: JSON.stringify({'data': data, "_token": token}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'array'
});
```

Hope this helps.